# Como crear un objeto a partir de un Array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Necesito un objeto en que las claves sean el tipo de cultivo concatenado con su año de plantación ejemplo: "Tomates-2021" y el valor otro objeto en el cual la clave sea el id del administrador y el valor el nombre del administrador

```
const allData = [
  {
    area:1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1,
    año:2021,
  },
  {
    area:200,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2020,
  },
  {
    area:400,
    cultivo: 'Lechugas',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1,
    año: 2016,
  },
  {
    area:1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'LUIS',
    adminId:4,
    año: 2022,
  },
  {
    area:100,
    cultivo: 'Zanahorias',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1
    año: 2021,
  },
  {
    area:500,
    cultivo: 'Papas',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2015,
  },
  {
    area:600,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2020,
  }
]
```

Lo que hice hasta ahora fue esto, se que esta mal pero la verdad no se como continuar con el ejercicio, no tengo mucha experiencia y no me puedo imaginar una solucion para este problema si alguien me puede ayudar y de paso explicarme un poco gracias

```
const momonga = allData.reduce((acc, value) => {
    const name = value.cultivo+'-'+value.año;
    if(acc[name] == null) acc[name] = []
    acc[name].push(value.admin);
    return acc
   
  }, {});
  return momonga
```

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo que entendi, esto deberia servirte. Recorro todo el array y por cada elemento creo una `key` y un `val`.

- Para armar `key` concateno el cultivo y el año: `el.cultivo + "-" + el.año`
- Para armar `val` creo un objeto `{[el.adminId]: el.administrador}`, *el secreto aca esta en meter `el.adminId` entre corchetes, de esta manera su valor se guarda como el nombre de la clave del objeto. El valor lo pasamos sin corchetes.*

Finalmente creo un objeto con clave `key` y valor `val` y guardo este objeto en el nuevo array de resultados. Para pasar key, nuevamente lo envolvemos en corchetes, para que la propiedad en lugar de llamarse `key` a secas, tome el nombre del valor de dicha variable `key`

```js
const allData = [
  {
    area:1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1,
    año:2021,
  },
  {
    area:200,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2020,
  },
  {
    area:400,
    cultivo: 'Lechugas',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1,
    año: 2016,
  },
  {
    area:1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'LUIS',
    adminId:4,
    año: 2022,
  },
  {
    area:100,
    cultivo: 'Zanahorias',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId:1,
    año: 2021,
  },
  {
    area:500,
    cultivo: 'Papas',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2015,
  },
  {
    area:600,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId:2,
    año: 2020,
  }
  
]

let resultadoFinal = [];

allData.map(el => {
  const key = el.cultivo + "-" + el.año
  const val = {[el.adminId]: el.administrador}
  const res = {[key]: val}
  resultadoFinal.push(res)
})

console.log(resultadoFinal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Según comentario del OP, esto resuelve su pregunta:

```
const momonga = allData.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const name = value.cultivo + '-' + value.año;
  obj = {}
  obj[value.adminId] = value.administrador
  if (acc[name] == null) {
    acc[name] = obj
  } else {
    if (!Array.isArray(acc[name])) {
      let temp = acc[name];
      acc[name] = [];
      acc[name].push(temp);
    }
    acc[name].push(obj);
  }
  return acc
}, {});
console.log(momonga)
```

### Explicación de los cambios

1. En cada ciclo primero creamos un objeto vacio mediante la [sintaxis abreviada de asignación a {}](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#usando_el_argumento_propertiesobject_con_object.create) y luego lo rellenamos con los datos del **id** del administrador y su nombre mediante [la notación de corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes):

```
obj = {}
obj[value.adminId] = value.administrador
```

2. Se ha quitado esto, que siempre provocaba que hubiera un array conteniendo al objeto aunque solo fuera uno:

```
if(acc[name] == null) acc[name] = []
```

y se ha cambiado por esto:

```
  if (acc[name] == null) {
    acc[name] = obj
```

donde comprobamos si el objeto existe previamente o no. Y si no existe previamente le asignamos el objeto definido en el paso anterior, de nuevo mediante la **notación de corchetes**.

3. Y si existe quiere decir que ya lo hemos hecho antes en algún ciclo anterior, por lo tanto es probable que contenga ya un objeto o bien un array de objetos, lo cual comprobamos mediante el método [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```
  } else {
    if (!Array.isArray(acc[name])) {
```

donde, si no contiene un array de objetos será porque aún contiene un solo objeto, con lo cual primero pasamos a convertirlo a array de objetos antes de agregarle un nuevo objeto al array:

```
      let temp = acc[name];
```

y lo hacemos mediante una variable temporal **temp** a la cual le asignamos el objeto anterior, para después

4. redefinir el valor de ese objeto a array, mediante la [notación literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_literal_notation) vacía, sin elementos, y le incluímos como primer elemento el objeto anterior almacenado en **temp** mediante el método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
      acc[name] = [];
      acc[name].push(temp);
    }
```

5. Y finalmente le agregamos al array de objetos el objeto en curso del ciclo actual, el cual o bien acaba de ser creado en el paso 4 o bien ya estaba creado con algún elemento previo en algun ciclo anterior y no ha entrado en el paso 4:

```
    acc[name].push(obj);
  }
```

6. De este modo, al terminar el ciclo o bien devolvemos un solo objeto, o bien devolvemos al menos un array con dos objetos que en los siguientes ciclos puede ir incrementándose:

```
return acc
```

Aquí un ejemplo funcional con todo:

```js
const allData = [{
    area: 1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId: 1,
    año: 2021,
  },
  {
    area: 200,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId: 2,
    año: 2020,
  },
  {
    area: 400,
    cultivo: 'Lechugas',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId: 1,
    año: 2016,
  },
  {
    area: 1000,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'LUIS',
    adminId: 4,
    año: 2022,
  },
  {
    area: 100,
    cultivo: 'Zanahorias',
    administrador: 'JOSE',
    adminId: 1,
    año: 2021,
  },
  {
    area: 500,
    cultivo: 'Papas',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId: 2,
    año: 2015,
  },
  {
    area: 600,
    cultivo: 'Tomates',
    administrador: 'ESTEBAN',
    adminId: 2,
    año: 2020,
  }
]

const momonga = allData.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const name = value.cultivo + '-' + value.año;
  obj = {}
  obj[value.adminId] = value.administrador
  if (acc[name] == null) {
    acc[name] = obj
  } else {
    if (!Array.isArray(acc[name])) {
      let temp = acc[name];
      acc[name] = [];
      acc[name].push(temp);
    }
    acc[name].push(obj);
  }
  return acc
}, {});
console.log(momonga)
```

Comment: wow, si, es lo que buscaba!, muchas gracias y espero la explicación.

Comment: @FranciscoGiménez Acabo de agregar la explicación pendiente. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede eternamente pendiente y la comunidad lo sepa y pueda beneficiarse de ella tambíén. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo, gracias.